# Going back and forth between H2 on-disk and in-memory DB

Tags: java, h2

Is it possible to create an in-memory H2 database that is initialized with the contents of an on-disk H2 database, run some operations on it and then persist the in-memory database back into a database file?

The reason I want to do this is that I have some data processing (loading from external sources, calculating derived tables and creating indexes) that takes a long time using the on-disk database and I hope to speed this up by doing it in-memory.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601038/saving-in-memory-h2-database-to-disk

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you can accomplish this with the `SCRIPT` command.

First, open the on disk database.  Next, dump it to a script file with `SCRIPT TO 'initial.sql'`.  Next, open an in-memory database and import the script with `RUNSCRIPT FROM 'initial.sql'`.  Operate on the database in memory, then script it out again with `SCRIPT TO 'updated.sql'`.   Finally, run the updated script in a persistent database again.